# How to convert date like '2021-06-01T11:17:00-07:00' to get date time for particular location (New Delhi) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to convert date like '2021-06-01T11:17:00-07:00' to ISO standard? What is this format?

```
let date = new Date('2021-06-01T11:17:00-07:00');
console.log(date.getHours() + " :" + date.getMinutes());
```

I should get 11:17 but I am getting back 23:47

So something going wrong in understanding the correct format of date?

To reverse engineer,

If I convert date my expected date which is "2021-06-01 11:17:00" to IsoString then the value which I get is 2021-06-01T05:47:00.000Z
which is not equal to 2021-06-01T11:17:00-07:00

PS - So from comments I got to know this format is in MST which is 7 hours behind UTC

Comment: have you tried `new Date('2021-06-01T11:17:00-07:00')`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"convert to ISO standard"_? Your string appears to be a valid ISO 8601 format

Comment: When I am trying to extract the hours and minute from this date, its not giving the result which I am expecting, so either this date format is incorrect or my understanding needs to be udpated

Comment: You will be seeing the date in your own time zone. The given date has a timezone that is MST (Mountain Standard Time), and you are probably in India, in a  +05:30 time zone. When it is 11:17 in Salt Lake City, it is 23:47 in New Delhi. So it really depends if you want to see the time in MST... do you?? You will clarify things when you show the *code* with which you visualise your date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to see it in the Indian time zone. So how can I get a date from MST to IST ?

Comment: You *are* seeing it in Indian time zone. The input says it is 11:17 in Salt Lake City. That is the same time as 23:47 in New Delhi. What you describe is exactly what should happen. You are getting consistent output.

Comment: Did any answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input specifies a time zone, so it specifies a time at which in Salt Lake City it is 11:17. That same moment corresponds to 23:47 in New Delhi, which is your time zone.

So when you tell JavaScript to read the input, it will know it is a specification in Mountain Standard Time (-07:00), and will store the date in UTC. When you output the date as you do, JavaScript will use your locale and output it as 23:47, which is the *exact* same moment that the input specifies.

If you want the time to output as 11:17, then apparently you don't want to consider that it is a local time in Salt Lake City, but ignore that, and just consider it to be 11:17 in *your* time zone.

In that case, you should change the input, and *remove* the time zone specification:

```js
let date = new Date('2021-06-01T11:17:00'); // No time zone specified -> is interpreted as local time
console.log(date.getHours() + " :" + date.getMinutes());
```

If the input string is variable, you can strip the time zone by keeping only the first 19 characters of the input before passing it to the `Date` constructor.

But be aware that when you strip the time zone, you actually *change* the time specification in the input to a different one. It is no longer the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Vanilla javascript Date class? Should be able to pass that into the constructor and then convert it to the desired format. For example:
const date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

You could also try using the Moment library in Javascript, although many people are trying to move away from this.